# Como encontrar onde está a referência circular no GSON?

Tags: java, gson

Imagine que eu tenha essas classes:

```
public class A {
    private B b;
}

public class B {
    private A a;
}
```

E então eu tenha isso:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
a.b = b;
b.a = a;
Gson gson = new Gson();
String x = gson.toJson(a);
```

O resultado é um `StackOverflowError` (trunquei ele, mas consiste de um monte de repetições do que está abaixo):

> ```
> java.lang.StackOverflowError
>     at sun.reflect.UnsafeFieldAccessorImpl.ensureObj(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.UnsafeObjectFieldAccessorImpl.get(Unknown Source)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Field.get(Unknown Source)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.writeField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:124)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:238)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:950)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:950)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:113)
>     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:240)
>     at com.google.gson.Gson$FutureTypeAdapter.write(Gson.java:950)
> ```

Existem várias formas de se resolver a referência circular no GSON, tais como acrescentar o modificador `transient`, utilizar alguma estratégia de exclusão, etc. Entretanto todas estas formas só funcionam depois que eu já sei onde está a referência circular.

Ocorre que eu tenho um cenário onde há um conjunto com algumas centenas de classes distintas relacionadas a serem serializadas em formato JSON por meio do GSON. No meio desses objetos todos, há ao menos uma referência circular em algum lugar, mas localizá-la é como procurar uma agulha no palheiro. Sei que depois de identificada a referência circular, solucioná-la deve ser algo relativamente fácil. Como eu faço para descobrir onde está essa referência circular?

Ah, e estou em um projeto que está em fase de manutenção e em produção, portanto não posso simplesmente decidir substituir um monte de tecnologias por outras, introduzir ou excluir bibliotecas ou reprojetar um monte de coisas. Se assim fosse, eu usaria o Jackson no lugar do GSON, uma vez que o Jackson diz claramente onde está a referência circular quando isso ocorre.

Estou usando o GSON 2.5.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar o Jackson nas dependências afim de encontrar o ponto ou os pontos onde ocorrem referência circular, após isto voltar para o Gson e adicionar uma estratégia de exclusão nestes pontos

Comment: Se achar válido posso colocar algumas formas de aplicar estratégia de exclusão com o Gson

Comment: @brow-joe Vou tentar isso de colocar o Jackson só para rastrear as referências circulares. Quanto a estratégia de exclusão, creio que isso seja tópico para uma outra pergunta.

Comment: Boa tarde amigo ao ver https://github.com/google/gson/issues/440 uma possivel solução para seu problema é um downgrade para versão 1.7.1 tenta seguir essa linha, boa sorte

Comment: Acredito não ser a melhor solução, mas um workaround seria adicionar uma plugin de referencias cíclicas na sua IDE, pode auxiliar a encontrar o problema. Ex para o eclipse:
https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/stan-structure-analysis-java#group-details

Comment: Se voce esta utilizando o Intellij, existe esse plugin por exemplo: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/93-metricsreloaded que parece ter um profile para isso, identificar relacoes entre classes, pode checar. A parte disso, se for inviavel marcar todos como transiente e ir analizando, ou colocar um max deep ....

Comment: Um modo alternativo, porem rápido é: Se vc estiver usando spring. Coloca um @Component em todas as classes e tenta subir a aplicação, ai o spring vai dizer qual classe depende de outra. :D

Comment: Isso depende dos status dos objetos? Ou pelo simples fato de haver um grafo cíclico de dependência de classes isso ocorre?

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Eu já não trabalho mais na empresa que fazia esse sistema há dois anos e meio. Mas sim, dependia do status dos dados internos dos objetos.

Answer (score 1):

O problema seria o fato que ambos os objetos estão sendo Settados no outro e atrapalha a construção do JSON, para resolver o problema basta adicionar a anotação `@JsonIgnore` em um dos atrributos da classe. Se deseja ignorar o valor da variável de tipo A na classe B, basta apenas adicionar a anotação acima da declaração do atributo.
Exemplo:

```
public class B {
    @JsonIgnore
    private A a;
}
```

Lembrando que, ao solucionar dessa forma, o JSON da classe A viria com os dados da classe B porém B seria retornado sem a referência da classe A.